# Optimize assigning values to local variables in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way to combine the following and set `@FH_RecordKey` and `@VF_dept_seq` in one `SET` or `SELECT` statement?

```
    set @FH_RecordKey =(
        case @lnktble
            when 'ems' then (select FH_inci_id from FH_Catherine_live.dbo.FH_MAP_EMS_INCI where VF_ems_seq = @tempseq)
            when 'imaster' then (select FH_insp_id from FH_Catherine_live.dbo.FH_MAP_INSPID where VF_in_seq = @tempseq)
            when 'n5basic' then (select inci_id from [dbo].[VF_IncWorkTable] where inc_seq = @tempseq)
        END)


    set @VF_dept_seq = (
        case @lnktble
            when 'ems' then (select VF_dept_seq from FH_Catherine_Live.dbo.FH_MAP_EMS_INCI where VF_ems_seq = @tempseq)
            when 'imaster' then (select VF_dept_seq from FH_Catherine_Live.dbo.FH_MAP_INSPID where VF_in_seq = @tempseq)
            when 'n5basic' then (select dept_seq from [dbo].[VF_IncWorkTable] where inc_seq = @tempseq)
        end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `IF` statement rather than `CASE`

```
IF @lnktble = 'ems'
select  @FH_RecordKey = FH_inci_id ,@VF_dept_seq = VF_dept_seq
from FH_Catherine_live.dbo.FH_MAP_EMS_INCI 
where VF_ems_seq = @tempseq
ELSE IF @lnktble = 'imaster' /*...*/
```

Comment: Man, I knew there had to be a way.  I'll some tests and see which method is quickest.

Comment: The IF method took 20ms, whereas running through the two sets of Set/Case statements took 47ms.  Sweet.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select @FH_RecordKey = 
  (case statement here),
@VF_dept_seq = 
  (case statement here)
```

Comment: Thanks ganders.  The CASE and WHERE criteria are identical in both sets.  I was hoping to be able to just use one set of case statements.

Comment: I don't believe you can when assigning more than one value per case.